# Turn off message sending from iCloud?

Tags: iphone, messages, text

Whenever I send someone a text, I'm told that it shows that "myname@icloud.com" is sending the text and not my phone number. And when someone responds to "myname@icloud.com", I receive the message on my computer and Wi-Fi only iPad, but not my iPhone. Is there any way to only send and receive messages from a phone number?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35360/6533

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Settings go to Messages> Send & Receive and you should be able to set your preferences from there. Go to the "Start New Conversations From:" section and set your phone number to be the default.

[image]

If your phone number does not appear, turn FaceTime off and on. Phone number should show up

Comment: Thanks! For some reason my phone number didn't appear in the "Start New Conversations From:" table. I tinkered with it and by chance tried turning "iMessage" on and off and my number appeared there.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for ya!

Answer (score 1):

Go to

- Settings
- Messages
- Send & Receive
- Uncheck the email address(es) just leaving your phone number checked.

You should be good from there.